# Guice Creation Errors Magnolia

Tags: java, macos, tomcat, content-management-system, magnolia

I am working on a project for the company I'm employed by. They are using Magnolia CMS. I am getting this error in the console in Eclipse when I try to start the Tomcat server.

I have searched for a solution but am finding it difficult. I've tried reinstalling eclipse, tomcat, deleting the .m2 repository and rebuilding, cleaning the project, cleaning tomcat working directory, commenting out the config for log4j in magnolia.properties.

I've googled the errors but not found anything helpful. I have tried on a completely different machine and I get the same error so it might be something to do with the code rather than the environment. However, I have colleagues who are on windows who dont get this error. Any help would be appreciated.

Tomcat 8.5, mac osx 10.13.6 high sierra, java 8 update 191 (build 1.8.0_191-b12), magnolia version is not the latest version (I will find out and update).

```
    Initializing Log4J
Initializing Log4J from [WEB-INF/config/default/log4j.xml]
18-11-02 17:38:49 ERROR PUBLIC[main]info.magnolia.objectfactory.guice.GuiceComponentProviderBuilder: Magnolia failed to load module configuration with types {} and components {Key[type=info.magnolia.cms.pddescriptor.ProductDescriptorExtractor, annotation=[none]]=info.magnolia.objectfactory.configuration.ImplementationConfiguration@4e251e4d, Key[type=info.magnolia.cms.util.UnicodeNormalizer$Normalizer, annotation=[none]]=info.magnolia.objectfactory.configuration.ImplementationConfiguration@622f47c4, Key[type=info.magnolia.content2bean.Content2BeanProcessor, annotation=[none]]=info.magnolia.objectfactory.configuration.ImplementationConfiguration@56c25298, Key[type=info.magnolia.cms.filters.FilterManager, annotation=[none]]=info.magnolia.objectfactory.configuration.ImplementationConfiguration@210b1e0a, Key[type=info.magnolia.cms.beans.config.ConfigLoader, annotation=[none]]=info.magnolia.objectfactory.configuration.ImplementationConfiguration@3b12c7f8, Key[type=info.magnolia.cms.core.FileSystemHelper, annotation=[none]]=info.magnolia.objectfactory.configuration.ImplementationConfiguration@63167b60, Key[type=info.magnolia.cms.i18n.MessagesManager, annotation=[none]]=info.magnolia.objectfactory.configuration.ImplementationConfiguration@9ac51e8b, Key[type=info.magnolia.cms.license.LicenseFileExtractor, annotation=[none]]=info.magnolia.objectfactory.configuration.ImplementationConfiguration@e660a786, Key[type=info.magnolia.content2bean.TypeMapping, annotation=[none]]=info.magnolia.objectfactory.configuration.ImplementationConfiguration@a0a859f1, Key[type=info.magnolia.context.SystemContext, annotation=[none]]=info.magnolia.objectfactory.configuration.ImplementationConfiguration@f98910d0, Key[type=info.magnolia.cms.beans.config.VersionConfig, annotation=[none]]=info.magnolia.objectfactory.configuration.ImplementationConfiguration@b2d693be, Key[type=info.magnolia.init.MagnoliaConfigurationProperties, annotation=[none]]=info.magnolia.objectfactory.configuration.ImplementationConfiguration@69e0fc4f, Key[type=info.magnolia.jcr.registry.SessionProviderRegistry, annotation=[none]]=info.magnolia.objectfactory.configuration.ImplementationConfiguration@1fa6adc2, Key[type=info.magnolia.transformer.BeanTypeResolver, annotation=[none]]=info.magnolia.objectfactory.configuration.ImplementationConfiguration@be83187a, Key[type=info.magnolia.content2bean.TransformationState, annotation=[none]]=info.magnolia.objectfactory.configuration.ImplementationConfiguration@a57e83b8, Key[type=info.magnolia.content2bean.Content2BeanTransformer, annotation=[none]]=info.magnolia.objectfactory.configuration.ImplementationConfiguration@753582eb}. Please ensure you don't have any legacy modules present in your web application.
com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:

1) A binding to org.slf4j.Logger was already configured at [unknown source].
  at info.magnolia.objectfactory.guice.GuiceParentBindingsModule.configure(GuiceParentBindingsModule.java:85)

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:411)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:167)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:119)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorBuilder.build(InjectorBuilder.java:100)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:83)
    at info.magnolia.objectfactory.guice.GuiceComponentProviderBuilder.build(GuiceComponentProviderBuilder.java:149)
    at info.magnolia.objectfactory.guice.GuiceComponentProviderBuilder.build(GuiceComponentProviderBuilder.java:196)
    at info.magnolia.init.MagnoliaServletContextListener.contextInitialized(MagnoliaServletContextListener.java:168)
    at info.magnolia.init.MagnoliaServletContextListener.contextInitialized(MagnoliaServletContextListener.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4643)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5109)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
18-11-02 17:38:49 ERROR PUBLIC[main]info.magnolia.init.MagnoliaServletContextListener: Oops, Magnolia could not be started
com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:
```

[image]

Comment: Please do not post images of code or errors, because it makes it more difficult for us to help you with your issue.  It is always better to copy and paste the relevant code and/or errors into your question directly.  Please read [Why not to upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-to-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question), then [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: @JoeC I've updated the question

Answer (score 1):

What the error is telling you is that various type mappings are missing. Based on the mappings mentioned in the error, I'd guess that those are mappings normally described in `magnolia-core-x.y.z.jar:/META-INF/magnolia/core.xml`. Jar itself or at least the classes it contains must be on the classpath otherwise Magnolia would not get even as far in the startup as it did. How you can be missing the mapping file from the jar is a mystery to me.

Are you trying to compile Magnolia from the sources or using existing precompiled version? Or perhaps you have file with same name somewhere on the classpath that is loaded by classloader prior the correct one from `magnolia-core.jar`?

Comment: the problem was caused by  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <type>maven-plugin</type>
  </dependency> inside pom.xml